# Need to click close 2 times to close form with fade animation

Tags: c#, fade, flatui

So I use a smooth fade out animation, and for some reason, I need to click 2 times to exit the form. The form is using FlatUI (formSkin1)

Code:

[image: Code]

Close not clicked:

[image: Close not clicked]

Clicked once: (it goes a little bit transparent)

[image: Clicked once]

On the second click, it closes the form. How do I fix this so I need to only click it once?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, but the actual code as text.

Comment: I put your code in a new form and it works fine.